# cake php error version 1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

CakePHP Error
one error comes like this 
Error: The requested address “/” was not found on this server –

i created model, view,controller for photcategory and add the path in routes like following

Router::connect('/admin/photocategory', array('controller' => 'photocategory', 'admin' => true));

but when clicking siteroot.admin/photocategory error comes as
The requested address “/” was not found on this server –

Comment: Care to explain the situation in more detail? What uri are you trying to access?

Comment: take a look at your apache log files, it's most possible a problem with some .htaccess file.

Comment: I checked the htaccess file.no problem in that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to be enabling admin routing here?  admin routing allows you to use a url like http://yoursite.com/admin/photocategory/add

if you're looking to do that, then your Router::connect call should look like this:
`Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'photocategory', 'action'=>'index', 'admin' => true));`

if you're just looking to get a normal url like http://yoursite.com/photocategory/add, then you do not need to modify the config default config file - you do not need to add your Router::connect line.

Here's more info on the default routing in the cake manual:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration#Default-Routing-946